# Calibrator for unit speed curve

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, differential-forms, vector-fields, frenet-frame

**Non-existence of Almost Calibrator of Circle :** Assume that
$U$ is $\varepsilon$-open ball at origin in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

> Prove that there does not exist the following function : $f:
> U\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ s.t.
>   $$ f(c(t))=t$$ where $c(t)=(1,0)+ (\cos\ t,\sin\ t)$ and $$ |{\rm grad}\ f|(x)\leq 1 + C\cdot {\rm dist}\
> (x,c)^3 $$ for $x\in U$.

**Proof :** i) Polar Coordinate : Define $$
p :X:=(0,\infty)\times (\pi-\epsilon ,\pi+\epsilon )\rightarrow Y:=
\mathbb{R}^2 $$ by $$ p(r,\theta)= r \bigg( \cos\ t,\sin\ t\bigg) +
(1,0) $$

ii) $$ df = f_r \langle \partial_r ,\ \rangle +f_t\langle
\partial_t,\ \rangle
$$

Assume that $p^\ast \alpha =df$ so that $$ \alpha =A \langle V ,\
\rangle +B\langle \frac{1}{r}W ,\ \rangle$$

where $V=dp\ \partial_r,\ W=dp\ \partial_t$. Hence two condition on $\alpha$ are

1) $A^2+B^2 \leq 1+C|1-r|^3$ and 2) $f(1,t)=t$

which can be translated into :

1) $f_r^2+(f_t/r)^2 \leq 1+C|1-r|^3$ and 2) $f(1,t)=t$

iii) Consider a translation on $X$ : $T(a,b)=(a+1,b+\pi)=(r,t)$. If $F=f\circ T$, then

1) $F_r^2+(\frac{F_t}{1+r})^2
\leq 1+C|r|^3$ and 2) $F(0,t)=t$.

Hence $F=rH +t$ and $$ (H+rH_r )^2(1+r)^2  + (rH_t+1)^2 \leq 1+
2r+r^2 + C|r|^3  $$

Hence $H=rU$ so that $$r^2 (2U +rU_r)^2(1+r)^2  + (r^2 U_t+1)^2 \leq
1+ 2r+r^2 + C|r|^3 $$

Here left side has no $r$-term so that it is a contradiction.

> **Question :** Can we prove this intuitively ? ${\rm dist}\ (x,c)^2$ is possible ?

Comment: You must assume that $\varepsilon>2$; otherwise $c(t)$ is not in the domain of $f$. If $\varepsilon\leq2$, then $c(0)=(2,0)\not\in U$, and $f(c(0))$ is undefined.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $\nabla f=c'(t)$ along $c$. Hence we assume that
$f^{-1}(t) =\{ (1,0)+r(\cos\ t,\sin\ t)|0<r<2 \}$. Fix
$p=(1,0)+r(\cos\ t,\sin\ t)$ for some $r<1$ and $t$. At $p$, assume
that integral curve $\alpha$ satisfies $\alpha(0)=p,\ \alpha(l)\in
f^{-1}(l+t)$ and ${\rm length}\ \alpha|[0,l]=lr$.

Hence $lr=_{assumption}l|\alpha'| = \frac{l}{|\nabla f|} \geq \frac{
l}{1 + C|1-r|^3 }$ which is a contradiction.